# Combine Angular2 FormBuilder with API fetched data

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-formbuilder

I have a view for `Edit Profile` and I am fetching the data from remote server and then I want to populate the form with the data that is returned from the server. This is what I have tried and its working fine but I do not know if this is the correct way of doing it.

So inside the `ngOnInit(`) I am creating the `formBuilder` the form in reality is alot bigger than this so for the sake of keeping the question simple i have only added two fields

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.profile = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        lastName: ['Last Name'],
    });

   //Get profile data 
   this.getProfileData();

}
```

`getProfileData()` is the method that then calls the service to get the profile data

```
getProfileData() {
    this.service.profileData().then(data => {
        this.firstName = data.first_name;
        this.lastName = data.last_name;

    });
}
```

And inside the view i have

```
<form [formGroup]="profile" (ngSubmit)="profileEditForm()">
    <ion-item no-padding>
        <ion-label stacked>First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName" formControlName="firstName"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item no-padding>
        <ion-label stacked>Last Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lastName" formControlName="lastName"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

    <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!profile.valid" full>Submit</button>
</form>
```

My question is

1. Is there no way to bind the `formbuilder` fields with the response that I get from the api or the way I did it is the right way to do it?
2. Inside the view instead of `[(ngModel)]="firstName"` shouldn't `[(firstName)]` work?

Will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You seem to be mixing reactive and template forms; read through https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html which includes information on how to alter the current values in the form. Remove the `[(ngModel)]` binding entirely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the tip, I am checking it out

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe that helped alot and i was able to implement the solution perfectly fine without using ngModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `patchValue` (or `setValue`) when you have received the response. In model-driven form do not use two-way-binding with `ngModel`. You can achieve what you want by setting the values to the form controls. Here let's set the values after you have received the values:

```ts
getProfileData() {
    this.service.profileData().then(data => {
        this.patchValues(data);  // call function to set the values  
    });
}

patchValues(data) {
  this.profile.patchValue({
     firstName: data.first_name,
     lastName: data.last_name
  })
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, this gives me an error sayins property patchValues does not exist in type FormGroup

Comment: Typo, it should be `patchValue` not `patchValues` inside the `patchValues` function, sorry about that, updated answer, try now :)